# How to fix the usage of LinkedIn UGC Post API (Legacy) return success response but not really posted in the LinkedIn?

Tags: python, http, linkedin-api

I am trying to post content to a LinkedIn group using my personal account with text only using this [LinkedIn endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http) using Postman:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts
```

---

1. **Request header**. As the documentation noted, the request header requires this key and values: `X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0` so I add it in the header.
2. **Request body**. Then, here is the request body of the HTTP request:

   ```
    {
        "author": "urn:li:person:<my personal id>",
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "containerEntity": "urn:li:group:6519652",
        "specificContent": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                "shareCommentary": {
                    "text": "Hello, this is an automated message, please reply"
                },
                "shareMediaCategory": "NONE"
            }
        },
        "visibility": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "CONTAINER"
        }
    }
   ```
3. **Authorization token.** I have a token that I have input in the Authorization form in Postman.

   The token has these permissions: `email, openid, profile, r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, w_member_social` which based on the docs, these permissions is enough for posting content to LinkedIn groups using a personal account.

---

When I try to send this request, the response is this:

```
{
    "id": "urn:li:groupPost:6519652-7089457359953014784"
}
```

I assume this means the request is handled properly and should have posted the content with the corresponding message. But when I check in the group (`https://www.linkedin.com/groups/6519652/`), the post does not exist.

What is the bottleneck here for properly post messages to the group using a personal account? is it that the endpoints don't serve as the services anymore or what?